# SQL Server Multi Valued Columns Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need multi-valued columns divided into single values

```
SOS_ID ALLOCATED_PART_NBR   ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM   ALLOCATED_QTY
523    500~5008~038~5008    2302~~007~5û005       1~1~~~1~2
```

Note: if no values between `~` delimiter it should insert empty string.

I want the output like this:

```
SOS_ID   ALLOCATED_PART_NBR  ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM    ALLOCATED_QTY
523      500                 2302                   1
523      5008                ''                     1
523      038                 007                    ''
523      5008                5û005                  ''
523      ''/NULL             ''/NULL                1
523      ''/NULL             ''/NULL                2
```

Comment: You should post information about what solutions you have tried what errors you are receiving etc.

Comment: There are a lot of "Split String" functions available here on StackOverflow, that take a string and return a table where each row is one of the sub-strings (you get to specify a delimiter).  Check out using those to create tables that you can join to the original table to get the results you want.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is with those last two rows. All the 'easy' solutions need to assume there are the same number of 'fields' in the multi-valued columns. Is that a hard requirement?

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings offers 4 approaches with performance stats and pros/cons.  CLR is generally your best bet if you can.

Answer (score 1):

So... here's a method I got to work for what you wanted.  First, you need a table-valued function that will split a string into fields based on a delimiter, and which will pad out the number of rows returned to a specified length:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SplitString]') AND type IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] ( 
        @delimitedString nvarchar(4000),
        @delimiter nvarchar(100),
        @padRows int 
        )
/**************************************************************************
DESCRIPTION: 
        Accepts a delimited string and splits it at the specified
        delimiter points.  Returns the individual items as a table data
        type with the ElementID field as the array index and the Element
        field as the data

PARAMETERS:
        @delimitedString  - The string to be split
        @delimiter        - String containing the delimiter where
                            delimited string should be split
        @padRows          - Any rows less than this value will be padded
                            with empty rows (NULL means no padding)

RETURNS:
        Table data type containing array of strings that were split with
        the delimiters removed from the source string

USAGE:
        SELECT ElementID, Element 
        FROM asi_SplitString('11111,22222,3333', ',', NULL) 
        ORDER BY ElementID

***************************************************************************/
RETURNS @tblArray TABLE 
   (
    ElementID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Element nvarchar(1000)
   )
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @index int
    DECLARE @siStart int
    DECLARE @siDelSize int
    DECLARE @count int

    SET @count = 1;
    SET @siDelSize  = LEN(@delimiter);
    --loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
    WHILE LEN(@delimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @delimitedString);
        IF @index = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES (@delimitedString);
            BREAK;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES(SUBSTRING(@delimitedString, 1,@index - 1));
            SET @siStart = @index + @siDelSize;
            SET @delimitedString = SUBSTRING(@delimitedString, @siStart , LEN(@delimitedString) - @siStart + 1);
        END
        SET @count += 1;
    END

    IF (@padRows IS NOT NULL)
        WHILE (@count < @padRows)
        BEGIN
            SET @count += 1;
            INSERT INTO @tblArray VALUES ('');
        END

    RETURN;
END

GO
```

Now you need a sample table with data to test this with (based on your question):

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (SOS_ID nvarchar(10), 
                        ALLOCATED_PART_NBR nvarchar(400), 
                        ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM nvarchar(400), 
                        ALLOCATED_QTY nvarchar(400))

INSERT INTO TestTable (SOS_ID, ALLOCATED_PART_NBR, ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM, ALLOCATED_QTY)
VALUES ('523', '500~5008~038~5008', '2302~~007~5û005', '1~1~~~1~2')
```

Now, some code that will transform the data above into the result you wanted:

```
DECLARE @fieldCount int;
WITH TildeCounts AS (
    SELECT LEN(ALLOCATED_PART_NBR) - LEN(REPLACE(ALLOCATED_PART_NBR, '~', '')) AS TildeCount
      FROM TestTable t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEN( ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM) - LEN(REPLACE( ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM, '~', '')) AS TildeCount
      FROM TestTable t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEN(ALLOCATED_QTY) - LEN(REPLACE(ALLOCATED_QTY, '~', '')) AS TildeCount
      FROM TestTable t
) SELECT @fieldCount = MAX(TildeCount) + 1 FROM TildeCounts;

SELECT t.SOS_ID, a.Element AS [ALLOCATED_PART_NBR], b.Element AS [ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM], c.Element AS [ALLOCATED_QTY]
  FROM TestTable t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(ALLOCATED_PART_NBR, '~', @fieldCount)  a
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM, '~', @fieldCount)  b 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(ALLOCATED_QTY, '~', @fieldCount)  c
WHERE a.ElementID = b.ElementID AND b.ElementID = c.ElementID
```

What this does is it first gets the maximum number of fields in all the strings (so it can pad out the ones that are shorter).  It then selects from the table, CROSS APPYING the function to each column, filtering only for the rows where all the IDs match (line up).

Comment: It's actually "tilde" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to xml, then select the nth node from each one.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4a31/4)

```
DECLARE @max_field_count int = 6;

SELECT 
  SOS_ID
 ,ALLOCATED_PART_NBR  = CAST(N'<a>'+REPLACE(ALLOCATED_PART_NBR ,'~','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS XML).query('(a)[sql:column("i")]').value('.','varchar(max)')
 ,ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM = CAST(N'<a>'+REPLACE(ALLOCATED_SALES_ITM,'~','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS XML).query('(a)[sql:column("i")]').value('.','varchar(max)')
 ,ALLOCATED_QTY       = CAST(N'<a>'+REPLACE(ALLOCATED_QTY      ,'~','</a><a>')+'</a>' AS XML).query('(a)[sql:column("i")]').value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM MyTable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP (@max_field_count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM master.dbo.spt_values) n(i)
```